# How to stack overlayed buttons from based control

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a control template for a base dialog where it can contain predefined buttons that can display on top of the content. The problem is that the buttons are not stacking properly with the content.

This is the result I am getting currently:

[image: issue]

I am hoping to get something like this:

[image: final result]

This is the code for the base dialog resource:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BaseDialogTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type dialogs:BaseDialog}">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ContentPresenter"
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="PART_ButtonStackPanel"
                                Margin="10"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button x:Name="PART_OkButton"
                                MinWidth="80"
                                Margin="0 0 5 0"
                                Background="Yellow"
                                Content="Base Ok Button" />
                        <Button x:Name="PART_CancelButton"
                                MinWidth="80"
                                Margin="5 0 5 0"
                                Background="Yellow"
                                Content="Base Cancel Button" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type dialogs:BaseDialog}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource BaseDialogTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ContentPresenter and Grid containing the stack panel are both part of Grid.Row 0.  Try adding RowDefinitions to separate the content, something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BaseDialogTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type dialogs:BaseDialog}">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                         
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ContentPresenter"
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="PART_ButtonStackPanel"
                                Margin="10"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button x:Name="PART_OkButton"
                                MinWidth="80"
                                Margin="0 0 5 0"
                                Background="Yellow"
                                Content="Base Ok Button" />
                        <Button x:Name="PART_CancelButton"
                                MinWidth="80"
                                Margin="5 0 5 0"
                                Background="Yellow"
                                Content="Base Cancel Button" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type dialogs:BaseDialog}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource BaseDialogTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried doing something like this before, but it was not giving met the result I wanted. The buttons would not appear as if they were on top of the content (would not overlay the content)

Comment: Actually, I think this might my best option at this point. I am going to mark this as the answer. Thank you